# Convert string to double word using Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am very new to Python and I want to send a `string` as command double word. Can anyone please tell me how we can do this in Python?

Comment: Please edit your post to include an example showing sample input and the expected behavior

Comment: What do you mean about *send a string as command double word* ?